# Angular 2 property binding. Kinda working

Tags: angular

I thought it would be cool to use something very new on something very old. So I'm going to use Angular 2 to manage our fax queues in Sharepoint. I have plenty of time, so I'm just learning to get familiar for now. Anyway,

The app first displays a list of the queues, and when you click on one, will show the faxes in that queue. For now, I just want to show the title. Easy enough, I thought.

Here's the FaxListComponent:

```
export class FaxListComponent implements OnInit {

  public faxqueue: FaxQueue;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private _faxService: FaxService, private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let queuename = params['id'];
      console.log('Queue: ' + queuename);
      this._faxService.getFaxQueueByName(queuename)
        .subscribe(queue => this.faxqueue = queue);
    });
  }
}
```

And then the view is just:

```
<p>
  fax-list works!
</p>
<p *ngIf="faxqueue">
  Current Queue: {{faxqueue.Display}}<br/><br/>
  {{faxqueue | json}}
</p>
```

The odd thing is that the binding of the Display property does not show up, but it's in the json view:

```
fax-list works!

Current Queue: 

[ { "Id": 2, "Display": "East", "Name": "Incoming Fax East", "Url": "/casefile/Incoming%20Fax%20East/" } ]
```

Here are the important parts of the faxservice:

```
export class FaxQueue {
  Id: number;
  Display: string;
  Name: string;
  Url: string;
}

getFaxQueues() {
    return this._http.get('app/shared/faxqueues.json.txt')
      .map((response: Response) => <FaxQueue[]>response.json().data)
      // .do(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(
        function (error: Response) {
          console.error(error);
          return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
        }
      );
  }

getFaxQueueByName(queuename: string) {
    return this._http.get('app/shared/faxqueues.json.txt')
      .map((response: Response) => (<FaxQueue[]>response.json().data).filter(queue => queue.Display === queuename))
      // .do(data => console.log('data:' + data))
      .catch(
        function (error: Response) {
          console.error(error);
          return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
        }
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your faxqueue possibly an observable of an array-like and not an object?

Because getFaxQueueByName returns the result of a .map.filter, the result will still be an observable of an array-like.

If you just want the first value, try with

```
.first().subscribe(queue => this.faxqueue = queue)
```

Depending on the rest of your code, you may have to import the first operator (around the top of your module) like so:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'
```

Comment: Don't this so. This is from the FaxService:

    `export class FaxQueue {`
      `Id: number;`
      Display: string;
      Name: string;
      Url: string;
    }

and

    getFaxQueues() {
        return this._http.get('app/shared/faxqueues.json')
          .map((response: Response) => <FaxQueue[]>response.json().data)
          // .do(data => console.log(data))
          );
      }

Comment: Well that looks awful

Comment: Yes, it does ;) Might want to edit your original question with that? Either way, the result of your pipe json seems to show an array with a single object as one of its elements. Do you want to try to use {{ faxqueue.length }} instead of {{ faxqueue.Display }} to confirm?

Comment: getFaxQueues clearly returns an array but I agree with you it is strange that getFaxQueueByName would give an array. It would seem like an improvable method name. Any chance you can share the signature or the implementation of getFaxQueueByName?

Comment: added the service parts. Thanks

Comment: getFaxQueueByName returns the result of the .map.filter which always will be an array. Even if the app/shared/faxqueues.json.txt uses Display as a unique key, the return value of getFaxQueueByName will be an array-like. You either will want to rename faxqueue to faxqueues (in theory there could be more than one or no faxqueue you might want to ngFor into) or force it to have either a single object or be empty. Right now faxqueue is always an observable of an array-like which is likely not what you expected/wanted: FaxQueue is a class, your faxqueue property is an array.

Comment: OK, that Observable with a filter seemed like voodoo to me anyway ;-)  I changed my view to `{{faxqueue[0].Display}}`, and it's now displaying the value, so you are correct. How can I force `getFaxQueueByName` to return only one object instead of an array?

Comment: I got it. Used find instead of filter. Thanks for your help

Comment: I just updated the answer using my preferred way, but yes, find works too